# Couldn't Connect Private DNS (Own DNS)

Tags: settings, connection-issues, dns

I have created my own DNS resolver for blocking some web pages and I can't figure out how to use it on Android. If I configure the DNS of any other device to use my DNS, it works like a charm (I've tested this both Windows and Ubuntu).

I tried configuring it in the Private DNS section of an Android, but it keeps saying "Couldn't Connect". If I use `1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com` instead, it works.

So, my question is:
What are the requirements for a DNS Provider to be configurable in the Android's Private DNS section?

Comment: Does your DNS resolver support DNS over TLS/DoT?

Comment: Yes. When I started looking at the differences between my DNS and Cloudflare, I realized I didn't have support for DoH and DoT. So I applied the necessary changes to support both.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have the rep to just use the comment so this is likely a far cry from a good answer.*

The verbiage where you can specify does state hostname so (without rooting?) we have to let the system resolve the hostname. You could use `one.one.one.one` as well, for the sake of less typing.

I would suspect it's just a typo but you might also check if you entered `-com` or `.com` in your device. If you're using the address as entered in the OP, it should be `1dot1dot1dot1.cloudflare-dns.com`.

I could be mistaken but, since Android 9, it seems like any private DNS app on the branded Play Store requires the use of VPN tunneling contrivance, on the device. It also looks like the only check it makes is that the TLD field does not begin with a number, as far as how it decides to validate it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the `-com`. It was a typo, I've edited the question. I'll read your answer carefully tomorrow.

Comment: No problem. I'm of the inclination that there is not a non-hostname answer, on Android 9+ Play branded devices, for the behavior you want so I would think you could leave it marked as unanswered. I believe this was changed to enforce DNS over TLS.